# What are the available ways/resources to create jpeg (or pdf) graphs/charts using java

Tags: java, pdf, graph, charts, jpeg

I'm looking for ways to create JPEG(or PDF) graphs/charts using JAVA. Any suggestions?

Ultimately I want to make a PDF report, but I figured that even if I get the graph in JPEG then I can use a JPEG to PDF converter to make it a PDF.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [Jasper Reports](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/)
- [iText](http://itextpdf.com/)
- [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/)

Comment: Both Jasper Reports and JFreeChart sit on top of iText, as does [Eclipse's BIRT](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/) (Business Intelligence Reporting Tools) and various commercial projects.

Answer (score 5):

We are using [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) for this. I do not know of other options, but this has served us well.

Answer (score 3):

It is NOT the best idea to "convert" a jpeg to PDF, because the JPEG still contains of pixels then. If you can, do produce vector charts which will look much nicer and produce a smaller PDF.

See these sites:

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-svggrph/
- http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/index.html (can produce PDF directly)
- http://www.jfimagine.com/order.html (free for non-commercial)

I would prefer JFreeChart, since I used it successfully for years, and it always was stable and reliable.

Comment: Yup Daniel, I'll most probably use JFreeChart as well.

Answer (score 0):

JFreeChart + [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) is a reasonable combo for producing PDFs with images.